# Can we use one optimizer for GAN model?

Tags: pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I have seen lots of GAN tutorials, and all of them use two separate optimizers for Generator and Discriminator. Their code looks like this.

```
import torch.nn as nn

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def forward(self, x):
        pass

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def forward(self, x):
        pass
```

```
G = Generator()
D = Discriminator()

optimizerG = torch.optim.Adam(G.parameters())
optimizerD = torch.optim.Adam(D.parameters())
```

But, can we combine those optimizers into one as shown below? Is there any downside?

```
class GAN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.G = Generator()
        self.D = Discriminator()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        pass
```

```
model = GAN()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
```

Comment: Hi there! I think this is more of a machine learning question than this is programing question (you ask whether certain methodology makes sense, not how to code it). There is a huge difference and if you optimize both discriminator and generator at the same time, it just  does not make sense for GAN.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of optimizing the overall GAN loss function, the generator and the discriminator have just the opposite goal (the generator wants to maximize it while the discriminator wants to minimize it, leading to their **opposite gradient** when backpropagating). So when you put them in one optimizer, whenever one's parameters get closer to the optimal, those of the other one just goes further from the optimal. In the end, neither one gets optimized.

*(I'm having the same doubt recently and above there are just some of my naive comprehension. This is the first answer I make in this community since I just joint in for a short time. Sorry if my English is not easily comprehended for it's my second language. Hope this answer helps you!)*